# Why doesn't assigning a new value to a list element inside an if block (which is inside a for loop) not change the actual list itself?

Tags: python

> I have a list of words (words_list), and w is used to iterate through it. If w is equal to word, which is a user-inputted string, then w is replaced with asterisks. If I print out the words individually inside the for loop, the string with the matched word asterisked-out comes, but if I print the original list itself, there's no change whatsoever. What am I not understanding?

```
for w in words_list:
  if(w == word):
     w = "*" * len(word)
     print w,
print words_list
```

Comment: Assignment in Python doesn't mutate objects (unless you use the special indexed forms).  It just changes the name to refer to a new object.

Comment: Read or watch Ned Batchelder's [talk on Python names](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the element in the list

```
for i in range(len(words_list)):
  if(words_list[i] == word):
     words_list[i] = "*" * len(word)
     print words_list[i]
print words_list
```

Comment: I've almost got what you're saying, but just clarify a bit more for me. The comment by strubbly on my question says assignment in Python doesn't mutate objects. So why will the third statement work? Is it because we're using indices of the list?

Comment: @SidharthSamant strubbly is right. In you code, line 1 `for w in words_list` what happens is - `w` gets a copy of an element from `words_list`. So it is a new variable with its own value, it is not referencing the value in the list. So when you change the value of w it is not reflected in the words_list.

Comment: @utkbansal More pythonic: Iterate over `for i, word in enumerate(words_list)`.

Comment: @D.Everhard ageed! but normal iteration is what the OP was doing, so I did it the same way. And it seems to be easily understandable by new people.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i, w in enumerate(words_list):
    if w == word:
        words_list[i] = '*' * len(word)
```

This way you iterate over the list and get the index along with the current list entry. Then you can access the current list conveniently with `w`, and replace it by accessing its index.

Comment: Thanks! This is a great way!